# Why is initial value of 'i' always 49

Tags: c#

This is my C# code for printing multiplication table

```
using System;
namespace MultiplicationTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic value;
            int i;            
            value = "123456789";
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            foreach (char name in value)
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(name);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}",i,num,i*num);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

when i run the program the value of **i** starts from **49**.
The output is as follows for an input **6**
[image]

Comment: Why not just use a normal `for` loop from 1 to 9?

Comment: Because he wants to. There's absolutely no reason to not use foreach loop.

Comment: @Tarec: he's counting from one number to another. That's exactly what `for` loops are for. If he absolutely _has_ to use `foreach`, he should at least loop over `Enumerable.Range(1,9)` instead of decoding a string.

Comment: I am a beginner in c#. I only know Python. Just loved this style of iterations which is also in python `for i in xrange(1,10):`

Comment: @user2332665 C# can do the same thing: `foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1,9))`, but you need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file. This way you get a number, not a char, and don't have to care about encodings.

Comment: `System.Linq`? what does it do

Comment: @TobiasBrandt `for` loops are a clunky mechanism that usually violate the DRY principle. I agree that `Enumerable.Range(1, 9)` is far preferable to looping through the characters `'1'` - `'9'`, but `foreach` is preferable to `for`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Unicode code point of the digit 1 is 49. [`Convert.ToInt32()` with a `char` argument returns the code point of said argument.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A quick fix for this, if your multiplication values must be in a string, is to convert each digit into a string before converting to an int:

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(name.ToString());
```

But if you're performing multiplication on a series of numbers, you're probably better off with an int array instead. If you're calculating numbers, there's no reason to store them in a string.

Answer (score 11):

Because ASCII value of character `1` is `49`

Check This:

[image]

Comment: `s/ASCII/UNICODE/`. This is C# we're talking about :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that's actually not less true, it's just more specific

Comment: @sehe, I agree it's true, just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Check below output

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32('1')); //49
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32("1")); //1
```

To fix you program, convert char to string first

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(name));
```

Or just

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(name) - 48;
```

Comment: all types in C# have a built in `.ToString()` method, there's no need to explicitly write `Convert.ToString(name)`, `name.ToString()` is enough

Comment: Yes, they are the same. Given OP is using Convert.ToIn32, Convert.ToString gives more hints about type difference between string and char.